# Stop media player in BaseAdapter android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, baseadapter

I have a `Fragment` with a `ListView` which is a list of sounds, that is populated in this way:

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getActivity(), tit, desc, songs, filenames, mMediaPlayer));
```

MediaPlayer is given as parameter because i would like that when back button is pressed or app goes in background, the player would stop playing.
So i have override onPause and onDestroy method in my Fragment, but this just doesn't work. Sound continues playing even if app is closed. This is my code:

```
         @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
              mMediaPlayer.stop();
              mMediaPlayer.release();
              mMediaPlayer = null; 
          }
          super.onDestroy();
         }

         @Override
        public void onPause() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
              mMediaPlayer.stop();
              mMediaPlayer.release();
              mMediaPlayer = null; 
          }
          super.onPause();
         }
```

I play sounds in my `BaseAdapter` class, in this way:

```
public void playSound2(int pos){

        if(isPlaying){  
            mMediaPlayer.stop();  
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            isPlaying = false;

    }
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, songs[pos]);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;

    }
```

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion is: don't use the adapter to interact with the media player. Instead, attach an item click listener to your listview, like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...
    }});
```

and do whatever you want with the media player in the `onItemClick` callback.

That being said, you should reset your media player when inside your onclicklistener, like so

```
try {
       mPlayer.reset();
       mPlayer.setDataSource(trackToBePlayed); //trackToBePlayed is dependent on the select position
       mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mPreparedListener);
       mPlayer.prepareAsync();

} catch (IOException e) {

} catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {

}
```

And in the mPreparedListener, when ready, you do

```
mPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
};
```

This should be enough to point you in the right direction :)